# Error capturing video with opencv (python)

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, video-recording

I am currently doing a motion detection project that records video when motion is detected. I am having an error when recording the video.

This is the following error:

> error: (-215) img.cols == width && img.rows == height && channels == 3 in function cv::mjpeg::MotionJpegWriter::write

This is my code:

```
def takevid():
```

Comment: in your code, where is frame defined?

Comment: @chris i have changed the question to my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is scope of the variable `frame`. You either need to declare frame outside the while loop, just globally in the file, or pass it as an argument to `takevid`. Currently `frame` is only available in the while loop, but that when you call `takevid` only the global scope (i.e `camera`) is accessible, not that of the while loop.

The error is telling you that the size of `frame` is wrong, and most likely you would find the shape is `(0,0)` because there is nothing in that variable.

Comment: i will give it a try. Thanks a lot :)